# Garry's Mod: How to send a DLL?

Tags: c++, networking, dll, lua, garrys-mod

Garry's Mod provides a C++ API to create server-side and client-side DLLs.

As it is said in the article ["Creating Binary Modules"](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Creating_Binary_Modules), they must be placed in the `"garrysmod/lua/bin/"` folder, but what do I need to do if I'd like to send a DLL to a client, which is required for a lot of tasks, I think?

My DLL includes and executes local as required, but not networked (only if it was added manual to both sides).

What I have tried:

1. Tried to do nothing, just placed server-side and client-side DLLs in the server folder. Result: no DLL on the client.
2. Tried to add both DLLs to an addon's `bin`, and then added the addon to both the server and the client. Result: the game doesn't include the DLL from the addon's `bin` folder. I can't just add a DLL to a client, because I'd like to run a dedicated server with this DLL, so it should be sent and include by clients automatically. Here I tried to do it through addons, which are networked.
3. Tried `resource.AddFile (https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/resource.AddFile)` and `resource.AddSingleFile (https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/resource.AddSingleFile)` and `AddCSLuaFile (https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Global.AddCSLuaFile)` (I know, it's stupid, but I tried it anyway). All these functions can't send a DLL to a client.

Do you know any way to share DLLs to a client? Maybe I have to use `net.WriteData (https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/net.WriteData)` someway?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you should be asking this in the Garry's Mod community.

Comment: I'd be gladly, but I don't know, where is it.

Comment: There is no way to network DLLs from server to client on gmod. It is a security approach.

Comment: @Francisco That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If you could send a DLL to a client you would have full control over the client's computer, and you could e.g. scan for credit card numbers or format their hard drive.